# Filter out object from an array in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my function. In here I want to filter object from an array and pass it in to the note variable When I run the program its shows var note variable is undefined what can I do for that

Review below code

```
 datepicker.onSelect = function (checked) {
                  var state = (checked) ? 'selected' : 'unselected';
                  $scope.calDate = this.toLocaleDateString();
                  var note = $scope.tooltipsArray.filter(function (items) { return items.date === '$scope.calDate' })[0];
                  ModalService.showModal({
                      templateUrl: 'scripts/directives/calendar/calendarModal.html',
                      controller: 'calendarModal',
                      inputs: {
                          calendarDate: $scope.calDate,
                          calendarNote: null,
                          dateSelected: state
                      },
                      size: 'sm'
                  }).then(function (modal) {
                      modal.element.modal();

                  });



              };
```

[debugger screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5tTx.png)

Comment: Can u please post the tooltipsArray structure?

Comment: $scope.tooltipsArray = [
                  {
                      date: new Date(),
                      text: 'sumudfffffffffffffffffffffffff'
                  },

                  {
                      date: new Date(2018, 8, 30),
                      text: 'aswdefvsdffcc'
                  }     
              ];
This is only demo array I entered those objects by manually. Thank you

Comment: Updated the answer , may be that's will help you

Comment: First thing you need to remove strings around `$scope.calDate`. Second you need to make sure that the comparison is valid (items.date and $scope.calDate are in same format) and there is atleast a match. In case there is no match you will get a blank array in return and since you are looking for its `[0]` you are bound to get undefined error.

Answer (score 0):

One issue I can see in your code is you are using **$scope.calDate** as string

> change '$scope.calDate' to $scope.calDate

```
 var note = $scope.tooltipsArray.filter(function (items) { return items.date === $scope.calDate })[0];
```

And Also to get the current localeDateString , use the below code

```
$scope.calDate = new Date().toLocaleDateString();
```

**Stack Blitz**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-szy529?file=home/home.controller.js

Comment: Thank you. But its still give the same result

Comment: @sd_dewasurendra what's the value coming in $scope.calDate , can u please share that's too?

Comment: @sd_dewasurendra Check the stackBlitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-szy529?file=home/home.controller.js

Comment: @sd_dewasurendra I would also suggest you to use moment.js to format date properly.